# 2 массива в параметры функции

Tags: node.js

Как передать 2 массива в качестве двух параметров функции, чтоб потом их можно было идентифицировать(понять какой array 1 - какой array 2)? Например:

```
function foo(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{

}
```

Comment: Я чего-то не понимаю в вопросе? Чем не подходит `function foo(array1, array2) { console.log('array1:', array1); console.log('array2:', array2)}`?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Очень странно.... Я, вроде, пробовал такой вариант.... А ответ и правда элементарный. Спасибо.